# Prevent windows from sticking to others while being dragged?

Tags: settings, release-juno, pantheon

How do I stop the behavior where dragging windows across another window makes them "stick" together for a bit. I want to turn that behavior off completely.

Here's what I mean:

https://i.imgur.com/6F4XqMe.gifv